# How to reverse looping array items with modulus

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, refactoring, modulus

I'm writing a react component that when the forward **`handleClickLeft`** or backward  **`handleClickRight`** button is clicked, it loops through an array going forward or backward. I did this by using modulus logic. I am able to get the forward button **`handleClickLeft`** to work properly but I can't figure out how do the reverse **`handleClickRight`**. Here's my example code:

```
export default class Rooms extends React.Component {
   constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.state = {indexPos: [0, 1, 2]};
      this.state.itemArry = [{room1: 'this is room1'}, {room2: 'this is room2'}, {room3: 'this is room3'}, {room4: 'this is room4'}];

      this.handleClickLeft = this.handleClickLeft.bind(this);
      this.handleClickRight = this.handleClickRight.bind(this);
   }
   render() {   //Using index to show each item in the itemArry
      let firstItem = this.state.indexPos[0]
      let secondItem = this.state.indexPos[1]
      let thirdItem = this.state.indexPos[2]       
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li>this.state.itemArry[firstItem]</li>
           <li>this.state.itemArry[secondItem]</li>
           <li>this.state.itemArry[thirdItem]</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   }

   handleClickLeft(){     // This one is working, it loops through the array in order and only shows three items at once. Ex: every time the forward button is clicked, indexPos changes >> [0, 1, 2] --> [1, 2, 3] --> [2, 3, 0]... 
      let vals = this.state.indexPos;
      let arryLength = this.state.itemArry.length;
      this.setState({
         indexPos: [(vals[0] + 1) % arryLength, (vals[1] + 1) % arryLength, (vals[2] + 1) % arryLength]
      });
   }

  handleClickRight(){  //This one is NOT working. It should be going in reverse 
     let vals = this.state.indexPos;
     let arryLength = this.state.itemArry.length;
     this.setState({
        indexPos: [(vals[0] - 1 % arryLength), (vals[1] - 1 % arryLength), (vals[2] - 1 % arryLength)]
     })
  }
}
```

In **`handleClickRight`** function, when any of the indexPos value reaches 0, it breaks the script. I understand the reason behind it; it's because of the negative value. I used Math.abs():

```
indexPos: [Math.abs((vals[0] - 1) % arryLength), Math.abs((vals[1] - 1) % arryLength), Math.abs((vals[2] - 1) % arryLength)]
```

to keep every value positive but it gave me a different result where it only loops through 2 items after one of the indexPos value reaches 0.

This is what happens when using Math.abs():

```
indexPos: [0, 1, 2] --> [1, 0, 1] --> [0, 1, 0] --> [1, 0 , 1] ... etc
```

This is how I want `handleClickRight` to loop though:

```
indexPos: [0, 1, 2] --> [4, 0, 1] --> [3, 4, 0] --> [2, 3, 4] --> [1, 2, 3] --> [0, 1, 2]
```

I appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: You can't do it with modulus, because `-1 % length` returns `-1`, not `length - 1`.

Comment: I consider this a bug in Javascript's modulus specification, but that's how it is. You need to use a conditional instead of modulus.

Answer (score 6):

I guess you can acheive that by doing:

```
   targetIndex = (arryLength + (index- x)% arryLength ) % arryLength
```

where:

- index: is the location from where you want to look back
- x: is the number of items you want to look back

  ```
  explanation: 
   in Modulo arithmetic adding arryLength any number of times to an index and doing a mod % arryLength will not change the position of the index within the array
   -(index- x)% arryLength could result in a negative value
   -this value would lie between -arryLength and +arryLength (non inclusive)
   -now adding arryLength to the resulting value and taking the mod again we get a value between 0 and arryLength
  ```

Comment: I think this can be simplified to targetIndex = (arryLength + (index - x)) % arryLength.

Comment: @FocusedWolf It cannot. That only works if `x` is within 1 `arrayLength`. As soon as you go over it you'll get the negative numbers again. If you try it with an `arrayLength` of 6, an `index` of `0` and an `x` of 13, you get (6 + (0 - 13)) % 6 = -1.
You have to do the modulo operation once to get the "correct" negative number and correct for multiple cycles, and then another operation to get the actual answer. Just as the commenter mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code snippet might help to loop through the array in the reverse direction, without the check for bound.

```
int len = arr.length;
int j = len - 1;
j = ( j - 1 + len ) % len
```